# Criar JSON com javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for

Queria saber como faço para criar um json pegando os dados de outro json usando um for

```
var imdb = {
  "title": "Justice League", 
  "content_rating": "PG-13", 
  "original_title": "", 
  "metadata": {
    "languages": [
      "English"
    ], 
    "asp_retio": "1.85 : 1", 
    "filming_locations": [
      "Leavesden Studios", 
      "Leavesden", 
      "Hertfordshire", 
      "England", 
      "UK"
    ], 
    "also_known_as": [
      "Justice League"
    ], 
    "countries": [
      "USA"
    ], 
    "gross": "", 
    "sound_mix": [
      "Dolby Digital EX", 
      "12-Track Digital Sound", 
      "Dolby Atmos", 
      "DTS(DTS: X)", 
      "IMAX 6-Track", 
      "Sonics-DDP", 
      "Auro 11.1"
    ], 
    "budget": "$300,000,000              (estimated)"
  }, 
  "release_date": "2017-11-17", 
  "director": "Zack Snyder", 
  "url": {
    "url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0974015"
  }, 
  "year": "2017", 
  "trailer": [
    {
      "mimeType": "video/mp4", 
      "definition": "480p", 
      "videoUrl": "https://video-http.media-imdb.com/MV5BODgxMGNmZGMtZDRlNS00NmY5LWFhMWEtOTYyY2M1ZGRiNWNhXkExMV5BbXA0XkFpbWRiLWV0cy10cmFuc2NvZGU@.mp4?Expires=1510767701&Signature=C1mwUKXcw-15NSv59mT1x80KKDaH6y3Kqr0-CYukkYD3kMMIjgZD5-CGkvNCIvVVwHrVxKFvylzPyXIKXhunaeX9wTToX63L0HCmeGQkZ2k5MfTcCuH~drSEHvjfkzIjwjaB6IqJl6N8HAxKse6HRVshm9GcH1uzlHGgoX~Qfns_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAILW5I44IHKUN2DYA"
    }, 
    {
      "mimeType": "video/mp4", 
      "definition": "SD", 
      "videoUrl": "https://video-http.media-imdb.com/MV5BOTQyZTM3ZWQtZGFkYS00ZmVhLWE3YTQtNDU1OWUyNDI2MjkzXkExMV5BbXA0XkFpbWRiLWV0cy10cmFuc2NvZGU@.mp4?Expires=1510767701&Signature=kVjQra9dODbBQ1dDQmocxyanoazz8FxA50M8dVWAfBJk4DxkDW4rdwyDel3oUWGKyvWVmbTLfYfuXKoFLb~MPT~p6CUpTG1g6vE8h2izkRmnHvuiU8kOWHutpjhL88HjtcKCkJYnKy4ebXvKNOYhs2Lsx7qQLoMYhPFNw7FK-iQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAILW5I44IHKUN2DYA"
    }, 
    {
      "mimeType": "application/x-mpegURL", 
      "definition": "auto", 
      "videoUrl": "https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi2454436121/hls-1509753918405-master.m3u8?Expires=1510767701&Signature=GfwQhkIRwiBFfcdmK6pf6k8fZUJyi0C44b2m9iEgQWi1qu1io4KolFxH67EIL1DrfgYuASozJx8VI-bjHTcSAzcSD9QCtrwOjbwcPIm8TPlJ1HpbS8GARnr-iynTVm5pLumOz~6KreC3Cj3ziws5rlqC-dBzZVYsSyexwSALq6FNx0FhaIEjAdprby-TSrPPnUAA3NYg1eAvPuwTzTYZZJG6-HwL8x5iPidaiDhlHnfJtnNjYanHqL78zYXMhnP4T2C2LEpoTW~yFXzcYD--a1TNS-92EQU~KBN9m5MRZf4yYp8UVnOnsIgz3GihQy1e1tqJ7oSui9Q8uLuYz3BI3Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA"
    }
  ], 
  "length": "121", 
  "cast": [
    {
      "character": "Diana Prince /              Wonder Woman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjUzZTJmZDItODRjYS00ZGRhLTg2NWQtOGE0YjJhNWVlMjNjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTg4NDI0NDM@._V1_UY44_CR6,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2933757/?ref_=tt_cl_t1", 
      "name": "Gal Gadot"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Antiope", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU0NTc4MzEyOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY0ODkzMQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000705/?ref_=tt_cl_t2", 
      "name": "Robin Wright"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Arthur Curry /              Aquaman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI5MTU5NjM1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc4MDk0Mw@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0597388/?ref_=tt_cl_t3", 
      "name": "Jason Momoa"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Queen Hippolyta", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwOTQ5NTc3OTVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDY4MDc1MDYx._V1_UY44_CR1,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001567/?ref_=tt_cl_t4", 
      "name": "Connie Nielsen"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Lois Lane", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4NjExMjI1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc0MjY2OQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0010736/?ref_=tt_cl_t5", 
      "name": "Amy Adams"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Bruce Wayne /              Batman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI4MzIxMTk0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTU5NjA0Mg@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000255/?ref_=tt_cl_t6", 
      "name": "Ben Affleck"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Barry Allen /              The Flash", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwMjQ3ODgxOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzc4NjE4NTE@._V1_UY44_CR17,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3009232/?ref_=tt_cl_t7", 
      "name": "Ezra Miller"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Mera", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0MjA1ODU0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTczNTkwNjE@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1720028/?ref_=tt_cl_t8", 
      "name": "Amber Heard"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Clark Kent /              Superman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxNTExMzUzOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTI1MjA3OTE@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0147147/?ref_=tt_cl_t9", 
      "name": "Henry Cavill"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Martha Kent", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4ODQ5NTgxNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDkwMDgyMg@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000178/?ref_=tt_cl_t10", 
      "name": "Diane Lane"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Iris West", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNmRhNDM5YzMtMmU4Zi00Y2E2LWIzYzMtN2QwMmY3MTdmYTlhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU0NDUwNTc@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4169922/?ref_=tt_cl_t11", 
      "name": "Kiersey Clemons"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Henry Allen", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5MzM5NzUzMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjEyMDY5Mg@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001082/?ref_=tt_cl_t12", 
      "name": "Billy Crudup"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Commissioner Gordon", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2NTI5NzQ1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjI1NDEwMDI@._V1_UY44_CR2,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0799777/?ref_=tt_cl_t13", 
      "name": "J.K. Simmons"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Steppenwolf", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTIyNjM0MzU0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTIxMzg1MQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001354/?ref_=tt_cl_t14", 
      "name": "Ciar\u00e1n Hinds"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Alfred Pennyworth", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5Mzg2NDY5OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDQwNzA0Mg@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000460/?ref_=tt_cl_t15", 
      "name": "Jeremy Irons"
    }
  ], 
  "imdb_id": "tt0974015", 
  "rating": "8.6", 
  "genre": [
    "Action", 
    "Adventure", 
    "Fantasy"
  ], 
  "rating_count": "4,322", 
  "storyline": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy. Together, Batman and Wonder Woman work quickly to find and recruit a team of metahumans to stand against this newly awakened threat. But despite the formation of this unprecedented league of heroes-Batman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman, Cyborg and The Flash-it may already be too late to save the planet from an assault of catastrophic proportions.", 
  "description": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy.", 
  "writers": [
    "Chris Terrio", 
    "Joss Whedon"
  ], 
  "stars": [
    "Ben Affleck", 
    "Gal Gadot", 
    "Jason Momoa"
  ], 
  "poster": {
    "large": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDgwNjMwNjM1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA2Njk5MzI@._V1_.jpg", 
    "thumb": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDgwNjMwNjM1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA2Njk5MzI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < imdb.cast.length; i++){




            obj =
              [
                 {
                    "full_name": imdb.cast[i].name,
                    "link": imdb.cast[i].link
                 },
              ]


            console.log(obj)
          }
```

Esta sendo exibido isso no console:

15[object Object]

Comment: Provavelmente o exemplo que você postou na pergunta não é o mesmo que você tem na sua aplicação, logo o que entendi do problema é que você concatenou uma string (possivelmente) com um objeto.

Comment: Onde está criando a variável obj? Se não está, insira um var ou um let antes dela. Depois, de um consolelog nos itens individualmente para ver o conteúdo. Pode ajudar.

Comment: @DiegoSantos eu preciso pegar os valores 'name' e 'link'  de 'cast' e colocar eles em outro json

Comment: Respondi abaixo, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim resolve?

```js
var imdb = {
  "title": "Justice League", 
  "content_rating": "PG-13", 
  "original_title": "", 
  "metadata": {
    "languages": [
      "English"
    ], 
    "asp_retio": "1.85 : 1", 
    "filming_locations": [
      "Leavesden Studios", 
      "Leavesden", 
      "Hertfordshire", 
      "England", 
      "UK"
    ], 
    "also_known_as": [
      "Justice League"
    ], 
    "countries": [
      "USA"
    ], 
    "gross": "", 
    "sound_mix": [
      "Dolby Digital EX", 
      "12-Track Digital Sound", 
      "Dolby Atmos", 
      "DTS(DTS: X)", 
      "IMAX 6-Track", 
      "Sonics-DDP", 
      "Auro 11.1"
    ], 
    "budget": "$300,000,000              (estimated)"
  }, 
  "release_date": "2017-11-17", 
  "director": "Zack Snyder", 
  "url": {
    "url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0974015"
  }, 
  "year": "2017", 
  "trailer": [
    {
      "mimeType": "video/mp4", 
      "definition": "480p", 
      "videoUrl": "https://video-http.media-imdb.com/MV5BODgxMGNmZGMtZDRlNS00NmY5LWFhMWEtOTYyY2M1ZGRiNWNhXkExMV5BbXA0XkFpbWRiLWV0cy10cmFuc2NvZGU@.mp4?Expires=1510767701&Signature=C1mwUKXcw-15NSv59mT1x80KKDaH6y3Kqr0-CYukkYD3kMMIjgZD5-CGkvNCIvVVwHrVxKFvylzPyXIKXhunaeX9wTToX63L0HCmeGQkZ2k5MfTcCuH~drSEHvjfkzIjwjaB6IqJl6N8HAxKse6HRVshm9GcH1uzlHGgoX~Qfns_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAILW5I44IHKUN2DYA"
    }, 
    {
      "mimeType": "video/mp4", 
      "definition": "SD", 
      "videoUrl": "https://video-http.media-imdb.com/MV5BOTQyZTM3ZWQtZGFkYS00ZmVhLWE3YTQtNDU1OWUyNDI2MjkzXkExMV5BbXA0XkFpbWRiLWV0cy10cmFuc2NvZGU@.mp4?Expires=1510767701&Signature=kVjQra9dODbBQ1dDQmocxyanoazz8FxA50M8dVWAfBJk4DxkDW4rdwyDel3oUWGKyvWVmbTLfYfuXKoFLb~MPT~p6CUpTG1g6vE8h2izkRmnHvuiU8kOWHutpjhL88HjtcKCkJYnKy4ebXvKNOYhs2Lsx7qQLoMYhPFNw7FK-iQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAILW5I44IHKUN2DYA"
    }, 
    {
      "mimeType": "application/x-mpegURL", 
      "definition": "auto", 
      "videoUrl": "https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi2454436121/hls-1509753918405-master.m3u8?Expires=1510767701&Signature=GfwQhkIRwiBFfcdmK6pf6k8fZUJyi0C44b2m9iEgQWi1qu1io4KolFxH67EIL1DrfgYuASozJx8VI-bjHTcSAzcSD9QCtrwOjbwcPIm8TPlJ1HpbS8GARnr-iynTVm5pLumOz~6KreC3Cj3ziws5rlqC-dBzZVYsSyexwSALq6FNx0FhaIEjAdprby-TSrPPnUAA3NYg1eAvPuwTzTYZZJG6-HwL8x5iPidaiDhlHnfJtnNjYanHqL78zYXMhnP4T2C2LEpoTW~yFXzcYD--a1TNS-92EQU~KBN9m5MRZf4yYp8UVnOnsIgz3GihQy1e1tqJ7oSui9Q8uLuYz3BI3Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA"
    }
  ], 
  "length": "121", 
  "cast": [
    {
      "character": "Diana Prince /              Wonder Woman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjUzZTJmZDItODRjYS00ZGRhLTg2NWQtOGE0YjJhNWVlMjNjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTg4NDI0NDM@._V1_UY44_CR6,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2933757/?ref_=tt_cl_t1", 
      "name": "Gal Gadot"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Antiope", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU0NTc4MzEyOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY0ODkzMQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000705/?ref_=tt_cl_t2", 
      "name": "Robin Wright"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Arthur Curry /              Aquaman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI5MTU5NjM1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc4MDk0Mw@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0597388/?ref_=tt_cl_t3", 
      "name": "Jason Momoa"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Queen Hippolyta", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwOTQ5NTc3OTVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDY4MDc1MDYx._V1_UY44_CR1,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001567/?ref_=tt_cl_t4", 
      "name": "Connie Nielsen"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Lois Lane", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4NjExMjI1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc0MjY2OQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0010736/?ref_=tt_cl_t5", 
      "name": "Amy Adams"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Bruce Wayne /              Batman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI4MzIxMTk0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTU5NjA0Mg@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000255/?ref_=tt_cl_t6", 
      "name": "Ben Affleck"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Barry Allen /              The Flash", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwMjQ3ODgxOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzc4NjE4NTE@._V1_UY44_CR17,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3009232/?ref_=tt_cl_t7", 
      "name": "Ezra Miller"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Mera", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0MjA1ODU0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTczNTkwNjE@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1720028/?ref_=tt_cl_t8", 
      "name": "Amber Heard"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Clark Kent /              Superman", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxNTExMzUzOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTI1MjA3OTE@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0147147/?ref_=tt_cl_t9", 
      "name": "Henry Cavill"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Martha Kent", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4ODQ5NTgxNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDkwMDgyMg@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000178/?ref_=tt_cl_t10", 
      "name": "Diane Lane"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Iris West", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNmRhNDM5YzMtMmU4Zi00Y2E2LWIzYzMtN2QwMmY3MTdmYTlhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU0NDUwNTc@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4169922/?ref_=tt_cl_t11", 
      "name": "Kiersey Clemons"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Henry Allen", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ5MzM5NzUzMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjEyMDY5Mg@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001082/?ref_=tt_cl_t12", 
      "name": "Billy Crudup"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Commissioner Gordon", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2NTI5NzQ1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjI1NDEwMDI@._V1_UY44_CR2,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0799777/?ref_=tt_cl_t13", 
      "name": "J.K. Simmons"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Steppenwolf", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTIyNjM0MzU0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTIxMzg1MQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001354/?ref_=tt_cl_t14", 
      "name": "Ciar\u00e1n Hinds"
    }, 
    {
      "character": "Alfred Pennyworth", 
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5Mzg2NDY5OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDQwNzA0Mg@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000460/?ref_=tt_cl_t15", 
      "name": "Jeremy Irons"
    }
  ], 
  "imdb_id": "tt0974015", 
  "rating": "8.6", 
  "genre": [
    "Action", 
    "Adventure", 
    "Fantasy"
  ], 
  "rating_count": "4,322", 
  "storyline": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy. Together, Batman and Wonder Woman work quickly to find and recruit a team of metahumans to stand against this newly awakened threat. But despite the formation of this unprecedented league of heroes-Batman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman, Cyborg and The Flash-it may already be too late to save the planet from an assault of catastrophic proportions.", 
  "description": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy.", 
  "writers": [
    "Chris Terrio", 
    "Joss Whedon"
  ], 
  "stars": [
    "Ben Affleck", 
    "Gal Gadot", 
    "Jason Momoa"
  ], 
  "poster": {
    "large": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDgwNjMwNjM1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA2Njk5MzI@._V1_.jpg", 
    "thumb": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDgwNjMwNjM1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA2Njk5MzI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
  }
}

var newArray = new Array();

//console.log(imdb.cast.length);
for(var i=0; i< imdb.cast.length; i++){
  newArray.push({"full_name": imdb.cast[i].name, "link": imdb.cast[i].link})
}
console.log(newArray);
```